# Why does vi sometimes use harder-to-reach keys?

Tags: history-of, original-vi

For example:

- `[[` and `]]` instead of `[` and `]`, and
- `G` instead of `g`.

Some ideas:

- Vim used these keys first, and they were backported to Vi (though `G` seems like an essential command for a code editor)
- Vi might have wanted to reserve them for prefix keys, as Vim did later (but why not `v` or `q`?)

I have both `nvi` and `vi` (from http://ex-vi.sourceforge.net/) on my computer (to check that this isn't some extension on a particular `vi` clone.)

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]! Not sure I see much problem with `[[` and `]]` (pressing the same key twice isn't that bad), but I kind of see the point with `G`... Not sure someone will know where this came from, but let's see, maybe yes.

Comment: If Vim would use `[`then how would `[s` and all the other mappings that start with `[` work? It would have to wait for a timeout, which has its own issues.

Comment: I'm surprised you didn't mention `:` to reach the command line while `;` does almost nothing.

Comment: @Quasímodo, on the keyboard vi was developed on `:` did not require pressing shift.  https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/a/a0/KB_Terminal_ADM3A.svg.  `f`/`t`/`;`/`,` is/was considered a useful set of motions to have easily accessible.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Bill Joy (the original author of `vi`) explains this in [*An Introduction to Display Editing with Vi*](https://docs.freebsd.org/44doc/usd/12.vi/paper.pdf).

> The `[[` and `]]` operations require the operation character to be doubled because they can move the cursor far from where it currently is.  While it
> is easy to get back with the command ``` `` ```, these commands would still be frustrating if they were easy to hit accidentally.

I did not find a justification for `G` but I presume it is similar.

Generally speaking, in `vi` short movements (`w`, `e`, etc.) are lower-case and long movements are upper case (like `H`, `L`, `M`).  Note that in `vi`, `gg` does not exist, and it was added by `vim`.